# How to select items according to their sums in SQL?

Tags: sql, sum

I've got the following table:

```
ID  Name    Sales
1   Kalle   1
2   Kalle   -1
3   Simon   10
4   Simon   20
5   Anna    11
6   Anna    0
7   Tina    0
```

I want to write a SQL query that only returns the rows that
represents a salesperson with sum of sales > 0.

```
ID  Name    Sales
3   Simon   10
4   Simon   20
5   Anna    11
6   Anna    0
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it like this, I think the join will be more effective than the where name in() clause.

```
SELECT Sales.name, Sales.sales 
FROM Sales 
JOIN (SELECT name FROM Sales GROUP BY Sales.name HAVING SUM(sales) > 0) AS Sales2 ON Sales2.name = Sales.name
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily get names of the people with the sum of sales that are greater than 0 by using the a HAVING clause:

```
select name
from yourtable
group by name
having sum(sales) > 0;
```

This query will return both `Simon` and `Anna`, then if you want to return all of the details for each of these names you can use the above in a WHERE clause to get the final result:

```
select id, name, sales
from yourtable
where name in (select name
                from yourtable
                group by name
                having sum(sales) > 0);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/605cf/2).

Answer (score 0):

This will work on some databases, like oracle, mssql, db2

```
SELECT ID, Name, Sales
FROM
(
 SELECT ID, Name, Sales, sum(sales) over (partition by name) sum1
 FROM <table>
) a
WHERE sum1 > 0
```